# Apache commons chain and Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, apache-commons

I have a legacy project based on apache commons chain. Since it is hard to test, I want to refactor it. Apache commons chain does not seem to support dependency injection, which I think is a necessity for testable code.

Does anyone know of a more test friendly framework that I could look at for chain of responsibility implementation? And does Spring provide something useful and inbuilt for chain of responsibility?

I am a complete newbie to apache commons chain, so please feel free to point out if stuff similar to dependency injection could be done with it.

Comment: This was helpful http://drummondsoftware.com/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-merge-spring-framework-and-commons-chain-chain-of-responsibility/

Comment: take a look at some examples here: http://www.dotkam.com/2009/07/26/apache-chain-with-spring/